# Bibliography in Texmaker

Tags: bibliographies, texmaker

I'm having some problems with my bibliography in Texmaker.
My code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

....

\cite{Johnson}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

I also created a new file (File > New) that I saved as `mybib.bib`:

```
@Article{Johnson,
author = {Edgar G. Johnson and Alfred O. Nier},
title = {Angular Aberrations in Sector Shaped Electromagnetic Lenses for Focusing Beams of 
Charged Particles},
journal = {Physical Review},
year = {1953},
volume = {91},
number = {1},
}

@phdthesis{Zoran,
author = {Zoran Racic},
title = {\'Etude et essais du spectromÃ¨tre Ã  plasma {DYMIO} de la  mission {MARS 96}},
publisher = {UniversitÃ© Pierre et Marie Curie},
year = {1996}
}
```

When I compile my `.tex` file, I only have a `[?]` appearing.

Could you tell me what my mistake is?

Comment: **How** do you compile your `.tex` file?

Comment: Are you running the normal sequence: `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex`?

Comment: you can choose bibtex as a compilation option in texmaker...

Comment: See also [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Your problem is that, after running `pdflatex` (or `latex` or whatever else) and `bibtex` (if you did it), you have to run `pdflatex` twice afterwards to get your document fully compiled.

In TeXMaker, if you want to be able to perform the full compilation cycle and view your finished `.pdf` file by just pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>, you can configure your 'Quick Build' command, choosing the wizard in the 'Configure TeXMaker' -> 'Quick Build' dialog, and adding, in the following sequence:

> PdfLaTeX
>
> Bibtex
>
> PdfLaTeX
>
> PdfLaTeX
>
> Pdf Viewer

If you want to use a different engine, substitute `pdflatex` with your preferred one. If the one is `latex` also substitute `Pdf Viewer` with `Dvi Viewer` in the above sequence.

Comment: Is there a way to permanently save these settings? I have entered them several times now.

Comment: I found the `Quick build` in the `Preferences...` menu instead of `Configure TeXMaker`. But it worked, thanks!

Comment: I performed the operations: PdfLaTeX, Bibtex, PdfLaTeX, PdfLaTeX, Pdf Viewer.  But not working, Could you guide me?

Answer (score 10):

Well, I speak Spanish and I was breaking my head over this a few moments ago (since I decided to try Texmaker), so I'll tell the basic points in the Spanish answer, which might be helpful.

- Go to Options > Wizard (or configure Texmaker)
- **In "Commands" (the top section), uncheck the *"Use a "build" subdirectory for output files"* (so sad now we'll have to use a crowded folder)** (actually this is the root of this issue)
- In "Compiling" select the *PdfLatex + Bib(la)tex + PdfLatex(2x) + View Pdf* option for the "Quick compile command"

Basically, from now on what you'll have to do is press **F1** (the quick compile shortcut), or set the compiling arrow at the upper bar to "Quick compile" (in my language it's just "Compile") and click there.

You won't need to touch the the "see pdf" arrow, since that's just for visualization.

The whole problem, actually is because Texmaker can't find the *.aux* file in the build subdirectory.

Comment: If you still face error, check if you've included a bibliography style. I for example used `\bibliography{apacite}`. In case you're using the same style, don't forget to add `\usepackage{apacite}`.

Comment: The third bullet finally worked for me!! Thank you!

Comment: In fact you CAN use bibliography AND a build directory. You just have to Options -> Configure Texmaker then modify the "Bib(la)tex" field to add the build directory in parameter like so : `bibtex .\build\%`

Answer (score 5):

This was my solution share it with you I hope will be helpful

[image]

Comment: please notice that the language of the site is English. Your answer might not accessible for users who do not speak spanish