# BibTeX in Texmaker

Tags: bibtex, texmaker

I am trying to create my own BibTeX file and use it in my TeX file. I am using Texmaker as the editor.

This is the content of my BibTeX file as of for now:

```
@ARTICLE{introtobiorec,
author = {Anil K. Jain and Arun Ross and Salil Prabhakar},
title = {An introduction to biometric recognition},
journal = {IEEE Trans. on Circuits and Systems for Video Technology},
year = {2004},
volume = {14},
pages = {4--20}
}
```

I have included

```
\usepackage{cite}
```

I also tried using

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

I include the BibTeX file (`MyBibFile.bib`) as follows:

```
\bibliographystyle{style}
\bibliography{MyBibFile}
```

It does not really throw any error but it does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: This question is much the same and includes texmaker-specific instructions http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119805/bibliography-in-texmaker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really don't know what you mean by "does not work", but here are two things that could be wrong:

**Possible Problem 1:** You are not compiling your work properly. This is the way to do it when you use bibtex:

```
latex myarticle
bibtex myarticle
latex myarticle
latex myarticle
```

**Possible Problem 2:** You are not including any citations in your LaTeX document. bibtex will not automatically include all the references in your bib file. It will only include those that you cite in your LaTeX document. For example, if your tex file has something like this:

```
Smith et al.~\cite{Smith:2001:jas} first studied the problem of XYZ and concluded that ABC.
```

Note that `Smith:2001:jas` should be one of the keys in your bib file. If you have a proper citation like the one shown above, and compile your document like I indicated, then it should automatically generate a references section with the reference to the paper identified by the `Smith:2001:jas` key.

Comment: gosh.. i remebered that i had to compile several times.. tried it 3 times.. but 4 times..