# Citations in Texmaker using Mendeley to form a bibtex database

Tags: bibliographies

I'm fairly new to LaTeX and having trouble with citations when using texmaker.

I have used Mendeley to produce what i believe is the .bib file containing all relevant references. (File produced = library & Filetype = BibTex Database, when double clicked "library" is opening in TEXworks). The bibtex file (library) seems to be in the correct format i.e.

```
@report{refname,
abstract = {},
author = {},
doi = {},
file = {},
issn = {},
journal = {},
keywords = {},
month = ,
number = {},
pages = {},
pmid = {},
title = {{}},
url = {},
volume = {},
year = {}
}
```

Within Texmaker i have the generic Latex source saved as testdoc.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
Blahblah \cite{refname}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{library}
\end{document}
```

however within the PDF my citations do not appear to work and have the warning message

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `refname' on page X undefined on input line XX.
No file testdoc.bbl.
```

Comment: Did you call BibTeX using the Key `F11`? Then again a latex run is required.

Comment: Possible duplicat [Bibliography in Texmaker](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119805)

Comment: Using package `biblatex` along with `biber` (processing tool, the `bibtex` replacement) could also be a good idea.

Comment: That seems to have solved the problem (F11 solution), thank you very much :). Just  to further my knowledge, what was i doing incorrectly i.e. what does pressing F11 while in texmaker actually do?

Comment: `F11` calls BibTex, which is reading your `.aux` file, sorting your Bibliography and generating the `.bbl` file.

Comment: Is there any reason why \cite{refname} works and \citep{refname} does not? Warning message is due to an Undefined control sequence

Comment: Where do you have `\citep{refname}` from? IIRC it comes from package `natbib`. But if you are free to choose, use biblatex.