# Texmaker bibliography quick build

Tags: bibtex, texmaker

I'm starting to use bibTeX to help me with reference in Texmaker. I'm using apacite package and I finally made it work after a help from a Youtube video. But in order for my PDF document to be fully updated it is no longer enough for me to do "quick build" rather it seems I have to do a combination of commands: PdfLatex, bibTex, PdfLatex, PdfLatex, View pdf. This is time consuming on a slow computer, and might make me consider going back to Word. Does anyone have a way around this? I did search the forum and found this one post: [Bibliography in Texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119805/bibliography-in-texmaker) where it is explained that there is a way around this but not exactly how it is done...

> \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
>
> \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
>
> \usepackage{pdfpages}
>
> \usepackage{apacite}
>
> \begin{document}
>
> \bibliographystyle{apacite}
>
> \bibliography{bib}

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the question? I think it was `F11` that starts `bibtex`.

Comment: You can use the *Options* menu co configure the Quick Build button. There you can set up the sequence of commands you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using TeXmaker's (any other IDE's shortcut keys) will not speed up the basic compilation process. However here are a few items for you.

1) If you are in the midst of just editing text then I suggest that you just use F6 then F7 to compile and view pdf OR use F2 then F3 for compile and view of dvi.  Caution: The exact placement of items on the page may change when the proper sequence is run.

2) If you have added a new reference, then you must run F6, F11, F6, F6, F7 in that order to resolve all the references.  (Note: If you are using internal citations to your own text, creating an index or glossary, then there may be additional steps for the complete document preparation.)

3) There are another options if your paths and installation are properly setup.  You could use either *texify* or a *make utility* appropriate for your Operating System. (Note: If you are new to LaTeX then I suggest that you stay with options 1) and 2) as needed.)

When I was teaching LaTeX to college students, I found this to be confusing for the students.  The most useful guidance I found for new users was 1) to compile and view as a normal document.  And then periodically run 2), the full sequence. (I advised that the first and last compile for a session when working on a document would be  F6, F11, F6, F6, F7. (pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex, pdf viewer).

Comment: I would add that it is possible to set up the Quick Build F1 to do all those commands in a row.

Comment: Could you point me to a some guideline on how to do that? Also, I guess that it will make the 'Quick Build' slower, right?