# Command \printbibliography not shows the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, koma-script

I am trying to show the bibliography in a LaTeX document. But `\printbibliography` does nothing. I am using `biblatex` with `bibtex8` as backend. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[liststotoc,bibtotoc,a4paper,12pt,parskip,final]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=30mm,bottom=40mm,bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}
\hbadness = 10000 % -> disable ``underfull \hbox'' warnings
\parindent 0pt % keine einrückung nach absätzen
\bibliography{literature}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter % keine kapitelnummern, römische seitenzahlen
    \include{./texFiles/titelblatt}
    \onehalfspacing
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
%   \include{./texFiles/abkuerzungsverzeichnis}
    \mainmatter
    \include{./texFiles/01_einleitung}
    \include{./texFiles/02_grundlagen}
    \include{./texFiles/03_konzept}
    \frontmatter
    \setcounter{page}{15} % seitenzahl counter auf 15 setzen
%   \include{./texFiles/literaturverzeichnis}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: welcome! Any error or warning messages?

Comment: hi and thank you.
no errors, but warning messages:
Class scrbook Warning: You've used obsolete option `liststotoc'.
Class scrbook Warning: You've used obsolete option `bibtotoc'.
Class scrbook Warning: Usage of deprecated font command `\sf'!
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'DJ-2015' on page 1 undefined on input line 2.
)
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 40.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:

the warning "LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 40." are very mysterious... the bib file is not empty.

Comment: Did you actually run BibTeX8 on your files? If so there should be a `.blg` file, what does it say?

Comment: a .blg is not created. iam using texmaker with the quick compile function in default mode.

Comment: Then your editor is not set up to run BibTeX or quick compile doesn't run a bibliography tool. (Check the menu for a bibliography compilation option) You can try and adapt the strategy for Biber in [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864), see also [Bibliography in Texmaker](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119805/35864). You might also want to consider switching from the legacy backend BibTeX8 to the up-to-date Biber.

Comment: ok, with this, it looks better. but after this changes iam getting a error message:
ERROR - Cannot find control file 'praxisbericht.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX? INFO - ERRORS: 1

Comment: Hmmm, WT..., after a single execution of biber it works now. very strange...
thanks for your help

Comment: @DynamicBit Does this mean, you got a solution?

Comment: @MaestroGlanz yes

Comment: @DynamicBit Then please post your solution as an answer and mark it as a solution.

Comment: the solution are the links from moewe and a "clean build"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are several problems in your code, some related to KOMA-Script, some to called, outdated packages.

Your code gives you several warnings you should read and then change your code like this:

```
\documentclass[%
  listof=totoc,
  bibliography=totoc,
  paper=a4,
  fontsize=12pt,
  parskip,           % <==================== then \parindent not needed! 
  final
]{scrbook}
```

Then you have the line `\usepackage{ae,aecompl}` calling two **outdated** packages.  Do not use this packages any longer!

If you use option `parskip` for class `scrbook`, then you can delete the line

```
\parindent 0pt % keine einrückung nach absätzen
```

At last you need to cite one or more bib entrys so that `biber` or `bibtex` are able to build an bibliography.  I added command `\nocite{*}` and used the BibLaTeX example bib file `biblatex-example.bib`.

And of course you have to be sure that the following order of program calls is done:  `pdflatex mwe.tex`, `bibtex mwe` or `biber`, `pdflatex mwe.tex`, `pdflatex mwe.tex`.  If you have problems with the used editor (usually bad configuration) use a terminal or console and use the above given commands to create your document.  If that runs, your TeX distribution is okay, and you can check the configuration of your editor ...

Complete MWE with commented packages from your example, which are not needed to show your problem:

```
\documentclass[%
  listof=totoc,
  bibliography=totoc,
  paper=a4,
  fontsize=12pt,
  parskip,           % <==================== then \parindent not needed! 
  final
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{ae,aecompl} % <====================== outdated, do not use!
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=30mm,bottom=40mm,bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}

%\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=bibtex8, % bibtex8 biber % <==================== change as needed!
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}

%\hbadness = 10000 % -> disable ``underfull \hbox'' warnings
%\parindent 0pt % keine einrückung nach absätzen
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

If you change from BiBTeX to Biber, you have to **change the backend** for `biblatex` (change in line `backend=bibtex8, % bibtex8 biber` in my MWE `=biblatex8` to `=biber`) and you **need to start** program Biber instead of BiBTeX (see commands shown above).