# Bibliography not appearing in PDF viewer

Tags: bibliographies

I have just started using LaTeX and have made a practice document where I am trying to add a reference list and it is not appearing in the PDF viewer. 
Here is the simple code I have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}

\section{introduction}
Hello there

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 

\bibliography{conttimeReferences}

\end{document}
```

Would be grateful for any tips - also keep in mind I am a beginner and my understanding is very limited.

Comment: Do you use `\cite{however you named an item in your bib file}` in your document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: How do you compile? Did you use `bibtex`? Is `conttimeReferences.bib` in the same folder as your `.tex` file?

Comment: Yes both files are in the same folder

Comment: And did you use bibtex?

Comment: I used Mendeley

Comment: OK, you need to compile with bibtex if you want a bibliography. which editor do you use? see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number for more information.

Comment: ok how do I do that? I use Texmaker

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119823/36296

Comment: Thank you for the links. However when I try to press F11 I get this message

Comment: Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: build\Practice Page.aux The style file: apacite.bst White space in argument---line 3 of file build\Practice Page.aux : \bibdata{My : Collection} I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no \citation commands---while reading file build\Practice Page.aux I found no database files---while reading file build\Practice Page.aux apacite.bst [2013/07/21 v6.03 APA bibliography style] (There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)

Comment: To make your life easier: don't use spaces in file names and don't use build directories

Comment: I see. I've changed that now and got this: Process started

I couldn't open file name `build\conttimeReferences.aux'

Process exited normally

Comment: Looks like it still uses a build folder.

Comment: I don't know how to not use a build folder. And in the configure settings the 'build' subdirectory box is not ticked.

Comment: Maybe you are still using an old `Practice Page.aux`. Press F6 before F11.