# Question mark instead of number reference - texmaker + mendley

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, texmaker

I am using latex for my thesis, using texmaker and mendley for the references. I have used latex and references beforem but I always used Overleaf, so I don't know what I am doing wrong with TexMaker because my refrences appear with a question mark `[?]` instead of with a number.

This is my code:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% IMPORT SETTINGS
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\input{../include/settings.tex}

% Documents' beginning
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{0}

% TITLE PAGE
\input{../include/title_page.tex}

% ENTITIES
\input{../include/empty_page.tex}
\input{../include/entities.tex}

% COPYRIGHT
\input{../include/empty_page.tex}
\input{../include/copyright.tex}

% DEDICATION [OPTIONAL]
% \input{../include/empty_page.tex}
% \input{../include/dedication.tex}

% ACKNOWLEDGMENTS [OPTIONAL]
\input{../include/empty_page.tex}
\input{../include/acknowledgments.tex}

% FINANCING [IF APPLIABLE]
% \input{../include/empty_page.tex}
% \input{../include/financing.tex}

% EPIGRAPH [OPTIONAL]
% \input{../include/empty_page.tex}
% \input{../include/epigraph.tex}

% RESUMO
\input{../include/empty_page.tex}
\input{../abstract/abstract_pt.tex}

% ABSTRACT
\input{../abstract/abstract_en.tex}

%\begin{spacing}{1} % change vertical space between toc, lof, lot and glossaries entries
\printglossaries
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\tableofcontents
%\end{spacing}

% INTRODUCTION
\input{../chapters/introduction/introduction_main.tex}

% METHODS
\input{../chapters/methods/methods_main.tex}

% RESULTS
\input{../chapters/results/results_main.tex}

% CONCLUSION
\input{../chapters/conclusion/conclusion_main.tex}

% REFERENCES / BIBLIOGRAPHY
\cleardoublepage
\bibliography{../references/TESE}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}


% INDEX [OPTIONAL]
% Each time you want to add an entry to index you need to use \index{text}
\newpage\null\newpage
\printindex

% APPENDICES [OPTIONAL]
\newpage\null\newpage
\input{../chapters/appendices/appendices_main.tex}



\end{document}
\end{document}
```

Here is an example of my `.bib` file called "TESE" generated through Mendeley:

```
@article{Manganaro2016,
author = {Manganaro, Lorenzo and Attili, Andrea and Dalmasso, Federico and Fausti, Federico and Giordanengo, Simona and Mazza, Giovanni and Monaco, Vincenzo and Sacchi, Roberto and Vignati, Anna and Cirio, Roberto},
journal = {PoS},
keywords = {Intro},
mendeley-tags = {Intro},
title = {{Control of the dose distribution in charged particle therapy}},
url = {http://pos.sissa.it/},
year = {2016}
}
@article{Katiaparodiphysikuni-muenchende2017,
author = {Katiaparodiphysikuni-muenchende, Cc Katia Parodi and Crespo, Paulo},
file = {:D$\backslash$:/Tese/mail{\_}Tese{\_}1.pdf:pdf},
pages = {3--5},
title = {{Master Thesis in M{\"{u}}nchen - Rita Rego}},
year = {2017}
}
```

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Did you run bibtex?

Comment: @samcarter how should I run it?

I am sorry if it seems like a "stupid" question but overleaf always did it automatically

Comment: Don't worry, this is one of the most often asked questions :) See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number for some explanation. And specifically for texmaker: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119823/36296

Comment: @samcarter I already read what you sent but how do I run bibtex?
If I run my .bib it appears this error:
Impossible to iniate command.
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Comment: Go to your main .tex document, run pdflatex first, then press `F1` to run bibtex and then again two times `pdflatex`

Comment: tried it and it still appears with de question mark

Answer (score 1):

Well, your given code is not **compilable** and have parts like

```
\bibliography{../references/TESE}
\input{../include/settings.tex}
```

I can not proof that the path `../references/TESE` to the bib file `TESE.bib` is correct.  And we do not have your `\input`ed files in your code ...

To get rid of that problems I suggest to start evaluating your error(s) with the following MWE, name it for example `mwe.tex`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Manganaro2016,
  author   = {Manganaro, Lorenzo and Attili, Andrea and 
              Dalmasso, Federico and Fausti, Federico and 
              onaco, Vincenzo and Sacchi, Roberto and 
              Vignati, Anna and Cirio, Roberto},
  journal  = {PoS},
  keywords = {Intro},
  mendeley-tags = {Intro},
  title    = {{Control of the dose distribution in charged particle 
              therapy}},
  url      = {http://pos.sissa.it/},
  year     = {2016},
}
@article{Katiaparodiphysikuni-muenchende2017,
  author  = {Katiaparodiphysikuni-muenchende, Cc Katia Parodi and 
             Crespo, Paulo},
  journal = {missing journal},
  file    = {:D$\backslash$:/Tese/mail{\_}Tese{\_}1.pdf:pdf},
  pages   = {3--5},
  title   = {{Master Thesis in M{\"{u}}nchen - Rita Rego}},
  year    = {2017},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{Katiaparodiphysikuni-muenchende2017} and \cite{Manganaro2016}.

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} % ieeetr
\bibliography{\jobname} % print bibliography created with filecontents

\end{document}
```

Then I get the following result without errors:

[image: resulting pdf]

Please copy this code to your computer/overleaf and compile it using the usual chain `pdflatex mwe.tex`, `bibtex mwe.aux`, `pdflatex mwe.tex`, `pdflatex mwe.tex`.

That should compile now without errors and it should not contain any `?`.

- If that is so, I guess that your given path to your bib file is wrong. Correct it and retry.
- If that is not so, the compiling of `bibtex mwe.aux` has not worked. Then please ask the support of overleaf for help!

After you get an compiling `mwe.tex` try your bib file with the mwe to make sure, that the bib file does not have errors.

Comment: Isn't that the very same answer again? Why no mark as dupe?

Comment: By the way, the LaTeX wikibook needs serious work on bibliograpies. Any hekp to fix it is welcome.