# Latex cannot find my .bib file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, jabref, undefined

I am using Texmaker in combination with Miktex and I am writing an article, but Latex can't find my .bib file. The .bib file is located in the same directory as my article latex file. I made .bib files in several ways: by using Mendeley, Jabref and by bibtex itself. In all three the cases I get warnings in Latex: "there were undefined references" and "citation 'citation1' on page 5 undefined".

I guess there is something wrong with my Latex?

Can someone please help me?

I made a MWEB of the report and a MWEB of the bibliography file.

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{article}

 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 \usepackage{cite}
 %\usepackage{natbib}

 \begin{document} 
 \pagenumbering{gobble}
 \title{Report}
 \author{Charlie}
 \maketitle
 \newpage
 \mbox{}
 \pagebreak

 \section{Theory}
 Blabla \cite{Gazibegovic2017}

 \pagebreak

 \section{Bibliography}

 \bibliography{biblio.bib}
 \bibliographystyle{plain}

 \end{document}
```

and the mweb from the bibliography

```
 @article{Gazibegovic2017,
 author = {Gazibegovic, Sasa. \textit(et al)},
 journal = {Nature},
 number = {7668},
 pages = {434-438},
 title = {{Epitaxy of advanced nanowire quantum devices}},
 volume = {548},
 year = {2017}
 }
```

I hope this information is sufficient for you to help me.

Kind regards

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have you run the entire path `pdflatex - bibtex - pdflatex`?

Comment: At the moment the most likely explanation is that you did not run BibTeX, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. If you did run BibTeX and still get warnings and errors, please consider adding a full MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) and show us the exact messages from the `.log` and `.blg` files (LaTeX and BibTeX log, respectively).

Answer (score 1):

Compiling the following [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) with

```
pdflatex document.tex
bibtex document.aux
pdflatex document.tex
pdflatex document.tex
```

gives the right result.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{key,
        author = {Author, A.},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Title},
        publisher = {Publisher},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

    \cite{key}

    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A comment to a working example on wikibooks would have had the same amount of information.

Comment: @Johannes_B that's only to develop my previous comment… Do I have to delete it?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I try to run my .bib-file to a bibTex, but i get an error message: "couldn't open file name 'biblio1.aux' " , while I saved my bibliography as a .bib-file. I don't know what an .aux-file is and why it says its an .aux-file while I saved it as a .bib-file.

Comment: Let say you have `source_tex.tex` and `biblio.bib`. You have to run `pdflatex source_tex.tex`, then `bibtex source_tex.aux` and twice again `pdflatex source_tex.tex`.

Comment: Hi, when I first run report.tex (source_tex.tex) I get the same errors as before: citation 'citation1' undefined. Then I run report.aux (source_tex.aux) I get two error messages and the file seems to have been dissapeared and then I run report.tex (source_tex.tex) twice I get the same errors: 'citation1' undefined. Do you know what is happening?

Comment: Please, instead of your `report.tex`, try compiling the MWEB above (save it in a new tex file).

Comment: I made a MWEB of my report.tex and my biblio.bib

Comment: How do you compile your tex file? Directly from TeXmaker?

Comment: Yes, I compile it with TeXmaker. First quick build and then into a pdf

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119823/151808